# Why does ^2/squared residual is calculating wrong answer in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, statistics, nan

I am trying to calculate RMSE in python with `pandas` data frame but do not want to use `sklearn` library for that. I have calculated it in excel and I have found that I have messed up with calculating the **squared residuals**. Could anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Here is the code I am using

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

path = r'D:\new result\Results\rmse\test\test_rmse.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(path)
df['sub'] = df['df']-df['df1']

a=df['sub']^2
a
```

The out of squared residual is wrong 
[image]

I need to correct this as I have calculated in excel **Here is the test data** where `df` and `df1` is present [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/61ff0a815383d678d1f479fa7cea97e420200612115426/7817ec](https:///wetransfer.com/downloads/61ff0a815383d678d1f479fa7cea97e420200612115426/7817ec)
[![excel calculation][5]][5]

Any suggestion??

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No screenshots of data.

Comment: I have provided the extracted excel sheet of the data. Any suggestions to calculate the squared residual?

Comment: MRE, please: something that can be copy/pasted and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have put the exact code. It can be copied from here. However, I do not know how to paste the output here: so that I have posted the data file also.

Comment: Use something like `print(df.iloc[0:5].to_dict())` to get a string for the first few rows, then use `pd.DataFrame(<that string>)` in your code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I understand that `iloc` is for selecting rows and it is `.to_dict()`  for making it in a dictionary. I have tried still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `^` is not the squaring operator in python, it's bitwise xor.  to take `a` to the power `b`, you do `a**b`